# How to check independence of two vector fields

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, control-theory

Consider two vector fields:

$f_1(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+3x_2^2x_3\\ 
x_3-x_1\\ 
x_2+x_3x_1
\end{bmatrix}$

$f_2(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
x_3+\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}\\ 
x_1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Does it exists a quick way to check if these vector fields are independent with respect to each other?

Comment: Compute the Lie bracket

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a quick way. Usually you would check if there are any $\alpha, \beta$, that are not all equal to $0$ and

$$\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2 = 0.$$

The third row shows that $\alpha = 0$ for any $\beta$. Then the first two rows imply $\beta = 0$.
$\alpha = \beta = 0$ is sufficient for the independence of $f_1$ and $f_2$.

If you only have two vectors, as it is in your example, you can also check the existence of $\alpha$, so that $\alpha f_1 = f_2$.

Note that $\alpha, \beta$ are not dependent on $x_1,x_2,x_3$.